# How to read media files in the library?

Tags: python, operating-system, speech-recognition

I am writing a script comparing two files with voices. And here's the deal. Before comparing two files:

```
score, prediction = verification.verify_files(os.path.join(root, tuples[0]), os.path.join(root, tuples[1]))
```

At this stage, everything is fine: I get the results of the answers (the comparison takes place).

But it's only worth recording a cycle of passing through files from different folders, where the `os.path.join()` method is used to indicate the files being compared, as I get an error (it can register payment in the file name or path to it):

```
0.0
0.0
RuntimeError: Error loading audio file: failed to open file spk_3_track_2.wav
```

So, some of the speakers' folders cycle normally. That is, the first folders suit him, but `spk3` - for some reason not.

The structure is such that the speakers root directory contains the folder spk1, spk2, spk3, etc., the file parameters are comparable (in each of the folders there are 4 files with people's voices).

What can be fixed? Here is the code:

```
# ECAPA-based recognition approach: comparing our voices
!pip install speechbrain
from speechbrain.pretrained import SpeakerRecognition
import os
from itertools import combinations


num_true=0
num_total=0

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/content/drive/MyDrive/speakers'):
    if not files:
        continue
    res = list(combinations(files, 2)) # we get lists of tuples: [(file 1, file 2), (file 1, file 3)...(file 3, file 4)]
    # print(res)

    for tuples in res:         # we go through each tuple in the list
        verification = SpeakerRecognition.from_hparams(source="speechbrain/spkrec-ecapa-voxceleb", savedir="pretrained_models/spkrec-ecapa-voxceleb")
    # print(f'{tuples[0]}', f'{tuples[1]}')
        score, prediction = verification.verify_files(os.path.join(root, tuples[0]), os.path.join(root, tuples[1]))
        num_total+=1
        if prediction == 'tensor([True])':
            num_true+=1

    # accuracy = num_true/num_total
    if num_total !=0:
      accuracy = num_true/num_total
      print(accuracy)
    else:
      print('You can't divide by zero')
```

Comment: Have you 'manually' checked the `spk_3_track_2.wav` file?

Comment: @hpchavaz, thanks for the tip. Manually launched, also an error. Apparently, the track is too short - only 11 seconds

Comment: @hpchavaz, no, it's not about the track and its duration. Posted another one - it also catches an error, although it is long enough (more than 30 seconds). Strange: next to him in the directory, the track is working correctly, and this particular one is erroneous